# Return specific page for a route like an api endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make an api endpoint which is like

https://cool.myXXXX.org/the_new_api/?key=XXXX?feature=OOOO

After surveying online, there is a method to create new api endpoint

But it's not enough, it forces me to use https://cool.myXXXX.org/the_new_api/route1/subroute

`function.php`

```php
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', function() {
    return 'the_new_api';
});

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'route1', '/subroute', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ), true);

    function my_awesome_func( $data ) {    
        return array(
            "data": 123,
            "user": 123456
        );
    }
});
```

Then, I want to customize a new route to set an api endpoint for GET request by returning specific php page.

If I have such file
`the_new_api.php`

```php
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myfriendsdomain.org');
header('Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, content-type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

$res = '';
switch ($_GET['key']) {
    case 'user_name':
        if ($_GET['feature'] === 'number') $res = array( 'user_name' => '1234');
        else $res = array( 'user_name' => 'Hello');
        break;
    case 'user_money':
        if ($_GET['feature'] === 'usd') $res = array( 'user_name' => '40');
        else $res = array( 'money' => '1460'); // yen
        break;
    default:
        die("Error");
        break;
}

die(json_encode($res));
```

How should I code in my `function.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer finally.

After creating the file `the_new_api.php` in the theme folder

Just get into `wp-admin`

Add new Page `the_new_api` and set the `Page Attributes` to be this php file the publish.

everything is gonna be right.